# Get pancake balance from a wallet

Tags: javascript, web3js, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to use Web3 library to learn, understand and play with blockchain. I can get information about my tokens etc on Binance smart chain and it's ok, but I'm trying to get this information from PancakeSwap, ApeSwap. The idea is to get the balance, pool and APR. I know that this is a contract, and what I tried is to get the information from this token: [https://bscscan.com/address/0xa80240Eb5d7E05d3F250cF000eEc0891d00b51C](https://bscscan.com/address/0xa80240Eb5d7E05d3F250cF000eEc0891d00b51CC)C that it's the contract for the pool with the tokens, but I always get 0. This is what I'm trying to do

```
const tokenAddress = '0xa80240Eb5d7E05d3F250cF000eEc0891d00b51CC'
const walletAddress = 'MI_WALLET_ADDRESS'

const minABI = [
{
  constant: true,
  inputs: [],
  name: 'name',
  outputs: [{ name: '', type: 'string' }],
  payable: false,
  type: 'function'
},
{
  constant: true,
  inputs: [{ name: '_owner', type: 'address' }],
  name: 'balanceOf',
  outputs: [{ name: 'balance', type: 'uint256' }],
  type: 'function'
},
{
  constant: true,
  inputs: [],
  name: 'decimals',
  outputs: [{ name: '', type: 'uint8' }],
  type: 'function'
},
{
  constant: true,
  inputs: [],
  name: 'symbol',
  outputs: [{ name: '', type: 'string' }],
  payable: false,
  type: 'function'
},
{
  constant: true,
  inputs: [],
  name: 'totalSupply',
  outputs: [{ name: '', type: 'uint256' }],
  payable: false,
  type: 'function'
}
]

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(minABI, tokenAddress)

const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call()
const wei = web3.utils.fromWei(balance)
const name = await contract.methods.name().call()
const symbol = await contract.methods.symbol().call()
const totalSupply = await contract.methods.totalSupply().call()
```

On this case, I get an error, but if I use the CAKE token, I get always 0. Do you know what I need to do, or if I need to use a different token or something?